# Internal server error for jquery.ajax in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

This is my ajax code

```
$.ajax({
                method: 'post',
                url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>"+"ci_ajax/test",
                data: {run : "1"},
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#index_all").html(data);

                },
                error: function(e) {
                    console.log('Error' + e);
                },
            });
```

and this is my server side method code in controller

```
public function test(){
    $post = $this->input->post("run");

    echo $post;
}
```

but in console log I receive this error

> POST http://localhost/ci_ajax/test 500 (Internal Server Error)

and console.log result for error function is

> Error[object Object]

any idea for resolve it?

Comment: what is the location of your .htaccess file

Comment: @pradeep there is two default .htaccess in codeigniter. One in root and one in application folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `method` to `type` from the ajax code

Your ajax should be like this :

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: "<?php echo base_url('ci_ajax/test'); ?>",
      data: {run : "1"},
      success: function(data) {
         console.log(data);
         $("#index_all").html(data);

      },
      error: function(e) {
         console.log('Error' + e);
      },
});
```

Your `test` method should be like this :

```
public function test()
{
    $post = $this->input->post("run");

    echo $post;
    exit;
}
```

Comment: show your controller `ci_ajax` class also and make sure `.htaccess` file should be in your base folder outside the application folder

Comment: remove the `.htaccess` file from the application folder and try again